# Transposing a timeserie of all countries

Tags: excel, vba, tableau-api

I am building a dynamic map that needs a specific formatting.
I have a horizontal time series to draw vertically, which is painful with the 228 countries I am dealing with.

Each column = category, and I must thus format Worldbank data on excel.

I attached an example of what outcome I seek. Thanks in advance!

Sandro

Data Horizontal

[image: Data Horizontal]

Required Data Format for all the countries

[image: Required format]

Answer (score 0):

Excel formula option for you.  You will need to adjust your cell ranges accordingly to your source data table.

Where you want the list of countries use the following formula and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,QUOTIENT(ROW()-ROW($A$2),COLUMNS($B$1:$D$1))+1),"")
```

Beside that use the following formula to get your list of years:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$2),COLUMNS($B$1:$D$1))+1)
```

Beside that use the following to pull your count values:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$5,QUOTIENT(ROW()-ROW($A$2),COLUMNS($B$1:$D$1))+1,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$2),COLUMNS($B$1:$D$1))+1)
```

A2:A5 is your list of country names
B1:D1 is your list of years
F2 is the start of your data column that you are building.

Proof of concept:

[image: Proof of Concept]